# Denon PMA amplifier on power when not in use

Tags: sound

I have a Denon sound amplifier and I use it mainly for music and movies using an auxiliary port. My question ( I want to prove it with scientific  answers ) is whether it is a problem if I leave the amplifier on power ( green light shows ) when I go to sleep. If I forget to use the controller and set the amplifier to standby ( red light ), is it a problem for health of the amplifier and the power consumption?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://usa.denon.com/us/product/hifi/amplifiers/pma800ne), the regular power consumption of your specific amplifier in watts is 200W while the standby power is .3W.

This suggests that you're okay leaving it in standby, but not leaving it in the fully on position.

Comment: I cannot find whether it is safe for the amplifier to leave it on (fully on). Will that 'burn' the amplifier?

Comment: This is just a personal opinion, but it's probably OK once in a while, but not a good general practice...